# Connect to Database Symfony 4 Flex

Tags: php, database, symfony, symfony4, symfony-flex

I am using **Symfony 4 Flex**.I using this [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) .
This is my  my database connection information
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_user: root
database_password: null

At first i install Doctrine

```
composer require doctrine maker
```

and then i set my database connection information:

```
 parameters:
       env(DATABASE_URL): 'mysql://root:null@127.0.0.1:3306/sona'
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

When I execute the

```
php bin/console   doctrine:database:create
```

I have this error

```
 In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103:

      An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


    In PDOConnection.php line 47:

      SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


    In PDOConnection.php line 43:

      SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


    doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction]
    [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You didn't follow the tutorial. It tells you to edit the .env file to edit the db connection info

Comment: hi.where is my .env file???I can not find

Comment: It should be in your project dir, same dir as composer.json

Comment: i have not this.so i must create this .it is right ???https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html

Comment: Nope.  If you used symfony create-project symfony skeleton then .env will have been made.  It is a . file so it's possible that you just not seeing it.  ls -la might reveal it.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html And the error message shows that you do have a .env file.  That is where the 'db_user' string is coming from.

Comment: thank you so much.My IDE don't show it for me..I find it finally

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in .env file that is located in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the below configuration in .env file then run the " php bin/console doctrine:database:create" so it will create the database.

```
# .env (or override DATABASE_URL in .env.local to avoid committing your changes)
# customize this line!
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"

# to use sqlite:
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/app.db"
```

Ref : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#installing-doctrine